# How can default values in Sequel Models be set?

Tags: ruby, model, default, sequel

Given the code below, how can default values be defined for the Model.
(let's say the default for :name should be 'Thing').

```
require 'pp'
require 'sequel'


DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table :items do
    primary_key :id
    String :name
end

items = DB[ :items ]


class Item < Sequel::Model

end

Item.create :name => 'foobar'
Item.create 

pp Item.all 
# => 
# >> [#<Item @values={:name=>"foobar", :id=>1}>,
# >>  #<Item @values={:name=>nil, :id=>2}>]
```

So, I'd like to have the second created Item set to #<Item @values={:name=>"Thing", :id=>2}> rather than :name=>nil.

Answer (score 8):

Subba's answer is the recommended way to do it in Sequel. It pushes the default into the database.

If you want to have defaults in the model instead of in the database, I recommend using a `before_create` or `after_initialize` hook to do them:

```
class Item < Sequel::Model
  def before_create # or after_initialize
    super
    self.name ||= 'Thing'
  end
end
```

The difference between `after_initialize` and `before_create` is when they are called.  `before_create` is recommended, since it won't set the default until right before the database `INSERT` method is called. However, if you want:

```
Item.new.name == 'Thing'
```

then you have to use `after_initialize`.

Comment: Do you mean `after_create`? `after_initialize` seems to be a plugin hook that is "called for all model instances on creation (both new instances and instances retrieved from the database). It exists mostly for legacy compatibility, but it is still supported." See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/model_hooks_rdoc.html

Comment: Just note that `after_initialize` needs a plugin - http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/AfterInitialize.html

Answer (score 4):

```
DB.create_table :items do
        primary_key :id
        String :name,:default => 'Thing'
end
```

should do the trick

from the sequel  Sequel::Database  source create_table block is evaluated inside Schema::Generator

```
def create_table(name, options={}, &block)
    options = {:generator=>options} if options.is_a?(Schema::Generator)
    generator = options[:generator] || Schema::Generator.new(self, &block)
    create_table_from_generator(name, generator, options)
    create_table_indexes_from_generator(name, generator, options)
end
```

inside Schema::Generator class method_missing handles String,text,boolean,number are handled by column method

```
def method_missing(type, name = nil, opts = {})
     name ? column(name, type, opts) : super
end
```

please refer to [sequel column for additional options](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Schema/Generator.html)

Answer (score 2):

I could set default values with using [defaults_setter](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/DefaultsSetter.html).

For all models.
(Call this before defining subclasses that want to use default_setter)

```
Sequel::Model.plugin :defaults_setter
```

Only for particular model.

```
Item.plugin :defaults_setter
```

or

```
Item class << Sequel::Model
  plugin :defaults_setter
end
```

You can set default value like this.

```
Item.default_values[:name] = 'foobar'
```

Thank you.